# How to write a Jest-enzyme test case for code in React useEffect whose dependencies are updated in its child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I have a parent component for filtering functionality

```
export const FilterComponent = ({data}) {
  const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = React.useState({});
  const [amenities, setAmenities] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (priceRange.min) {
      // code to filter based on priceRange
    }

    if(amenities.length) {
      // code to filter based on amenities
    },[priceRange, amenities])

  return (
          <select id="price" value={priceRange} onChange={(event) => setPriceRange(JSON.parse(event.target.value))}>
            <option value="">Price Per Night</option>
            <option value='{"min":0,"max":99}'>Less than $99</option>
            <option value='{"min":100,"max":299}'>$100 to $299</option>
            <option value='{"min":300,"max":499}'>$300 to $499</option>
            <option value='{"min":500}'>More than $500</option>
          </select>

    <MoreFiltersComponent setAmenities={setAmenities} amenities={amenities} />}
  )
}
```

I am using this parent component to display the filters like Price range and other filters that user can view on the screen and added test cases for them. I created a child component to this, MoreFiltersComponent, to display many other filters which user can view after clicking on More Filters button. amenities is part of MoreFilters but I created state for it in parent component and passing it as props so that I can run useEffect of parent component to check all the filters when there is any update.

```
export const MoreFiltersComponent = ({setAmenities, amenities}) => {

  const updateValue = (event, state, updateState) => {
   // code to update the state
  }
 
 return (
   <input type="checkbox" name="ac" id="ac" value="ac" onChange={(event) => updateValue(event, amenities, setAmenities)} />
 )
}
```

This is the test case I created to test the price range filter which is working fine

```
const setPriceRangeSpy = jest.fn();
const mockUseEffect = () => {
    useEffect.mockImplementationOnce((f) => f());
  };

it('should render the correct results for selected price range', () => {
    const event = {
      target: { value: '{"min": 0, "max": 99}' },
    };

    useStateSpy.mockImplementationOnce(() => [{}, setPriceRangeSpy]);
    renderedModule = shallow(<FilterComponent {...props} />);
    mockUseEffect();

    renderedModule.find('#price').simulate('change', event);
    
    expect(setPriceRangeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ min: 0, max: 99 });
    expect(renderedModule).toMatchSnapshot();
 }
```

I tried a similar test case for amenities but it doesn't work. I can't simulate the onChange event as the element isn't in this component and so the lines of code in useEffect where I filter based on amenities are uncovered. is there a way I can cover those lines of code as well ?

```
 const setAmenitiesSpy = jest.fn();
 const mockUseEffect = () => {
    useEffect.mockImplementationOnce((f) => f());
  };

 it('should render the correct results when there is no max price', () => {
   useStateSpy.mockImplementationOnce(() => [["ac", "tv", "wifi"], setAmenitiesSpy]);
   renderedModule = shallow(<FilterComponent {...props} />);
   mockUseEffect();

   expect(setAmenitiesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(["ac", "tv", "wifi"]);

 }
```

I get this error for amenities test case:

Expected: ["ac", "tv", "wifi"]

Number of calls: 0

I can't simulate the onChange event as the element isn't in this component and so the lines of code in useEffect where I filter based on amenities are uncovered. is there a way I can cover those lines of code as well ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you better not mocking `useState` and `useEffect`. It's definitely *implementation details* and while you can technically do that you will - and you probably reached this point - make any change harder and harder to include in test. Not telling that if you for any reason ever decide to reshape your state(say, making some part of it coming from props or context instead) you will need to completely rewrite your tests. It's not good.

Second, since `shallow()` still [does not work fine](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086) with `useEffect`. So just use `mount()`. Yes, it means you will have all nested components to be rendered in deep... until you explicitly mock them! See:

```
import { MoreFiltersComponent } from '../path/to/MoreFiltersComponent.jsx';

jest.mock('../path/to/MoreFiltersComponent.jsx', () => ({
 MoreFiltersComponent: function MoreFiltersComponent() {
  // so this is mocked React component that always returns null
   return null; 
 } 
}));

....
 const wrapper = mount(.....);
 // you still can search for this component, even if it's mocked and always returns null in render
 wrapper.find(MoreFiltersComponent)
```

Also you most probably will need [`act()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) from `react/test-utils`. Some enzyme's helpers like `simulate()` already call that while others maybe don't. This method ensures all the related `useEffect`/`useLayoutEffect` will be run and run in sync way. Without `act()` you may find `useEffect` is executed *after* test has been completed that does not make any sense.

Keeping all that in mind, we can test how `FilterComponent` works with `MoreFiltersComponent`(or more precisely with its mock):

```
  const wrapper = mount(<FilterComponent data={mockedData} />);
  act(() => {
    wrapper.find(MoreFiltersComponent).invoke('setAmenities')(['a','b']);
  });

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot(); // should be only those matched filters
```

PS I cannot answer how you can solve that task with mocked `useEffect` and `useState` and `shallow()`